# "forbidden error" when trying to access the bundled slick.css file in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, slick.js, bundling-and-minification

I am using slick-carousel in my `ASP.Net MVC` project. If I link the `slick.css` file through normal `<link>` tag in Html, it works fine. But if I bundle the `slick.css` file and render it in Html, it shows forbidden error(403).

**Working Solution**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/Slick/slick-theme.css" />
```

**Bundling the files**

```cs
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Slick").Include(
                    "~/Content/Slick/slick.css"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/SlickTheme").Include(
                    "~/Content/Slick/slick-theme.css"));
```

**Refering the bundled files**

```cs
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Slick")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/SlickTheme")
```

Can anyone please let me know why i am getting such error only when bundled?

Comment: Try to use reference of `SlickTheme` before `Slick`

Comment: @Sh.Imran : I changed the order but still the issue was there.

Comment: @Archana Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue it seems...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a slick specific issue, but the folder structure of slick's NuGet installation provokes it.

There is a problem if the bundle name matches a really existing folder in the web application, because then the request is not recognized as an access to the bundle, but to the folder which then isn't granted. So as you can see in my example, the bundle's naming scheme matches the folder.

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/slick").Include("~/Content/Slick/slick.css"));
```

After changing the bundle name as shown here (and of course the references), it works

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/slickstyle").Include("~/Content/Slick/slick.css"));
```